# Eclipse fails after installing JBoss Tools

Tags: jboss, nashorn, jboss-tools, jsdt, fedora-25

After installing JBoss Tools and restarting Eclipse IDE, I get following exception:

```
An error has occured. See the log file /home/abc/workspace/.metadata/.log
```

Eclipse does not start anymore. Can anybody help me, to fix this problem?

My setup:

- Eclipse Version: Neon 2
- OS: Fedora 25
- JBoss Tools Update Site: https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/

Log File:

```
!SESSION Wed Mar 22 21:41:43 CET 2017 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2017-03-22 21:41:43.812
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension
!SESSION 2017-03-22 21:41:43.742 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.v20170109-1424
java.version=1.8.0_121
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_CH
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-22 21:41:44.473
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension not found.

!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim.eclipse 4 0 2017-03-22 21:41:45.447
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim.eclipse [1051]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim; bundle-version="3.5.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim; bundle-version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"
       org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [1050]
         No resolution report for the bundle.  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"] because it is exposed to package 'org.eclipse.jetty.continuation' from resources org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] and org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]

Chain 2:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.servlets)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.wiring.bundle="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"
  org.eclipse.jetty.servlets [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server; uses:=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.server [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.server"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1599)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:47.664
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the commands from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' and 'org.eclipse.ui.actionDefinitions' extension points.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:47.664
!MESSAGE Commands should really have a category: plug-in='net.sf.eclipsecs.ui', id='CheckstylePlugin.PurgeCaches', categoryId='net.sf.eclipsecs'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:48.283
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the commands from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' and 'org.eclipse.ui.actionDefinitions' extension points.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:48.283
!MESSAGE Commands should really have a category: plug-in='net.sf.eclipsecs.ui', id='CheckstylePlugin.PurgeCaches', categoryId='net.sf.eclipsecs'

!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.xulrunner.initializer 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:50.274
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.jboss.tools.xulrunner.initializer [1068]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt


!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim.eclipse 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:50.281
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim.eclipse [1051]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim; bundle-version="3.5.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim; bundle-version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"
       org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [1050]
         Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"] because it is exposed to package 'org.eclipse.jetty.continuation' from resources org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] and org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]

Chain 2:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.servlets)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.wiring.bundle="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"
  org.eclipse.jetty.servlets [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server; uses:=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.server [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.server"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"] because it is exposed to package 'org.eclipse.jetty.continuation' from resources org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] and org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]

Chain 2:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.servlets)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.wiring.bundle="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"
  org.eclipse.jetty.servlets [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server; uses:=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.server [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.server"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]

!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.foundation.security.linux 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:50.282
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.jboss.tools.foundation.security.linux [997]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.security; bundle-version="1.1.100"
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.security; bundle-version="1.1.100"


!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim 2 0 2017-03-22 21:41:50.282
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [1050]
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"] because it is exposed to package 'org.eclipse.jetty.continuation' from resources org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] and org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.0.M0"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]

Chain 2:
  org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169"; osgi.identity="org.jboss.tools.vpe.cordovasim"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.servlets)(bundle-version>=8.1.3))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.wiring.bundle="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"
  org.eclipse.jetty.servlets [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.10.v20130312"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.server; uses:=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.server [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.server"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(&(version>=8.1.0)(!(version>=9.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.eclipse.jetty.continuation
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="8.1.14.v20131031"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-22 21:41:50.282
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.sac.ParserNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.batik.css.parser.Parser cannot be cast to org.w3c.css.sac.Parser
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.dom.parsers.AbstractCSSParser.getParser(AbstractCSSParser.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.dom.parsers.AbstractCSSParser.parseStyleSheet(AbstractCSSParser.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.parseStyleSheet(AbstractCSSEngine.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.restore(ThemeEngine.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.setCSSTheme(PartRenderingEngine.java:1399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1292)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1026)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.batik.css.parser.Parser cannot be cast to org.w3c.css.sac.Parser
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.sac.SACParserFactoryImpl.makeParser(SACParserFactoryImpl.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.sac.SACParserFactory.makeParser(SACParserFactory.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.dom.parsers.AbstractCSSParser.getParser(AbstractCSSParser.java:139)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the JBoss Tools, which you get from this update site is from 2014. It's too old. The correct update site link is: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/stable/updates/.

By now the latest stable version is 4.4.3.Final: http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/neon/4.4.3.Final.html

Other versions (development and nightly) you can find here: http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/neon/index.html

The best and easiest way to install jbosstools plugins to Eclipse is by using Eclipse Marketplace plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools.

Old, but still actual video with instructions of how to install JBoss Tools via Eclipse Marketplace plugin: http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the README.html on the /updates/stable page [1] to point users to the latest JBoss Tools releases [2].

[1] http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/

[2] http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/

Also updated the composite*.xml files in [1] to point to the Neon release, though this URL should not be considered current at all times (as you saw, it was pointing you at the JBoss Tools 4.1 release based on Eclipse Kepler, not the 4.4 release based on Neon).